# Sequential Random Numbers C++

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to pick a random word from a Dictionary, and instead of giving me random numbers, the numbers increase sequentially each time I run the program, for example if I get 17010 one run, I would get somewhere around 17025 or so the next run.

Here is my code:
If it helps, the length of the Dictionary is around 44000.

```
    //I initialize srand(time(0)) in my main function
    int numRand = std::rand()%Dictionary.size();
    std::string wordOne = Dictionary[numRand].getWord();
    sylCount -= Dictionary[numRand].getSylls();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to call `srand()` to seed the random number engine? E.g. call `srand(time(NULL));` once in your `main()`.

Comment: Don't use `rand()`, it's one of the worst PRNGs out there. Use a decent PRNG from Boost, such as mt19937.

Comment: 17010 and 17025 are not sequential

Comment: @pjs: You don't need Boost for `mt19337`. It's in `std::`, just include `<random>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++11, you can use its `<random>` library. Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for documentation. Prefer the `mt19937` generator - it is a higher-quality PRNG than `rand()` or something like that.

If you need the numbers to increase sequentially each time you run the program, you will need to save the number to a file at the termination of the program, then load it back in and perform your random-number generation in a loop, waiting until you get a number larger than the previous. (To be honest, I'm not quite sure why you need it to increase each time you run the program - that breaks the program's reproduce-ability, which will significantly hamper your ability to perform tests.)

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  I think mt19937 is definitely the stronger option. Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator (%) is not a good idea because it will not be random if the range of rand() is not a multiple of the dictionary size.

i.e. if the range of rand() was 0-9 and the dictionary was size 9 there would be twice as much chance of the output being 0 than any other number because 0%9=0 and 9%9=0.